# Nest class-validator minDate throws error even when the date is greater

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I'm using Nest with class-validator and attempting to validate that the date provided by the UI is no earlier than today using `@isDateString()` and `@MinDate()`

```
export class SchemaDto {
    @IsOptional()
    @IsDateString()
    @MinDate(new Date())
    myDate?: Date;
}
```

The data I am sending in is a Date Objected with the following date:

```
    Mon Oct 04 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

The error I am getting from class-validator is:

```
     minimal allowed date for myDate is Fri Oct 01 2021 15:57:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

**The problem:**

If I remove the minDate decorator, everything works fine but I would rather validate this common case.

info:
typescript: ~4.1.4

node: 12.4.0

class-validator:  0.13.1

nest: 7.0.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To validate with @MinDate

```
export class SchemaDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Transform( ({ value }) => new Date(value))
    @IsDate()
    @MinDate(new Date())
    myDate: Date;
}
```

But if value is optional, it might null or undefined, so:

```
export class SchemaDto {
    @IsOptional()
    @Transform( ({ value }) => value && new Date(value))
    @IsDate()
    @MinDate(new Date())
    myDate?: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `@Transform` approach in Hai An's answer works because it omits `@IsDateString` decorator which is included in the OP's question. If you intend to keep the `@IsDateString` decorator, you'll run into new errors when you use it alongside the `@Transform` decorator (`@Transform( ({ value }) => new Date(value))`).

The use of `@IsDateString` implies that you expect a date string in ISO8601 format as input. The issue is that `@MinDate` accepts an argument of type `Date` whereas what is passed to it at runtime in your case is a string. A look at [the validator implementation for MinDate](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/5f91937ddbf9d4247477d8c5993834d52d4c6294/src/decorator/date/MinDate.ts#L10) reveals that validation will fail if the value of the decorated property is not an instance of `Date`. Using the `@Transform` decorator to transform the date string into a date object is still a problem with `@IsDateString` because you get an error that the input received is not a valid ISO8601 date string. This happens because transformation occurs before decorators are applied. The good news is that [an issue with a PR attached is open here in the typestack/class-validator GitHub repo](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/1691) to fix the conflict that comes with using `@IsDateString` and `@MinDate` validators together — but it doesn't look like it'll be merged soon.

Solution? I suggest that you implement a custom decorator. You could keep the name of the decorator as MinDate so that when the [feat: Make minDate and maxDate support specifying dynamic date](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/pull/1692) PR gets merged/released, you only need to update your class-validator version and change your MinDate import path. Below is my implementation which makes a one-line change to [the original implementation](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/master/src/decorator/date/MinDate.ts) to allow MinDate receive a date string:

**custom-min-date.decorator.ts**

```
import { buildMessage, ValidateBy, ValidationOptions } from 'class-validator';

export const MIN_DATE = 'minDate';

/**
 * Checks if the value is a date that's after the specified date.
 */
export function minDate(date: unknown, minDate: Date): boolean {
  const dateObject: Date = typeof date === 'string' ? new Date(date) : <Date>date;
  return dateObject instanceof Date && dateObject.getTime() >= minDate.getTime();
}

/**
 * Checks if the value is a date that's after the specified date.
 */
export function MinDate(date: Date, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions): PropertyDecorator {
  return ValidateBy(
    {
      name: MIN_DATE,
      constraints: [date],
      validator: {
        validate: (value, args): boolean => minDate(value, args.constraints[0]),
        defaultMessage: buildMessage(
          (eachPrefix) => 'minimal allowed date for ' + eachPrefix + '$property is $constraint1',
          validationOptions,
        ),
      },
    },
    validationOptions,
  );
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your IsDate() by IsDateString() and this will do the conversion for you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).