# @MaxDate from class-validator not working as expected with Nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator

I don't have a lot of experience developing with Nodejs/Nestjs.
I'm developing a REST API where one of endpoints receives a User body with a birthday property.

I want to validate that date of birth is always before the current day.
This is a snippet of my code:

```
import { IsString, IsDateString, MaxDate } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsString()
  readonly username: string;

  @IsDateString()
  @MaxDate(new Date())
  readonly dateofbirth: Date;
}
```

And this is my entity:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  dateofbirth: Date;
}
```

However, when making a POST request I always get the same error and can't understand why:
`{"statusCode":400,"message":["maximal allowed date for dateofbirth is Mon Nov 01 2021 12:20:11 GMT+0000 (Western European Standard Time)"],"error":"Bad Request"}`

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: What are you sending  as a payload?

Comment: You got the error because there's an issue with using `@IsDateString` and `@MaxDate` or `@MinDate` decorators together. Here's [a detailed answer in response to a similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73668637/6388351).

Comment: You were so close! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77309233/6474744) should work :-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem when added `@Type(() => Date)` to dateofbirth from `class-transformer`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That works, but as Simon explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766694/6474744) the `MaxDate` would be stuck on the instant that the service starts running. You could fix that as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77309233/6474744)

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

1. Cast the string to `Date` with the `Type` decorator:

```js
@Type( () => Date )
```

2. Replace `@MaxDate(new Date())` with `@MaxDate(() => new Date())`

### Explanation

- Using `@Type( () => Date )` transforms whatever given to a `Date` object
- Using `@MaxDate(new Date())` creates a static date when the service is ran as [Simon mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766694/6474744). As a workaround, you can `delay` this instance creation to when the DTO runs with specifying the `MaxDate` argument as an arrow function: `@MaxDate( () => new Date())`

Partial code:

```js
@ApiProperty({ 
   type: 'string', 
   format: 'date',
   example: new Date(1986, 11, 11) 
})
@Type( () => Date ) // cast to Date type
@MaxDate(() => new Date(), {
    message: () => 
        `maximal allowed date for date of birth is ${new Date().toDateString()}`,
  })
dateOfBirth: Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The date passed into the Validator MaxDate is stored once when the service is started. So MaxDate is now comparing the date when the service started with the given date.

I did not find a solution to use the MaxDate Decorator with the current time.
At the end we compare the sent date with current time in the controller function (the old/classic way).

Comment: You were so close! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77309233/6474744) should work.